# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: while writing to a file in Python 3

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write the output of python script to a text file. The script runs for sometime and write the content to the file. But after sometime I get 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'

Below is my script.

```
def ancestor_map(id):
    
    row_icd = umls[umls['AUI'] == id]        
    cui = row_icd.CUI.to_string(index=False)               
    
    if cui in df_mdr_pt_llt['CUI'].values:                   
        match = df_mdr_pt_llt[df_mdr_pt_llt['CUI'] == cui]
        match = match[["CODE", "STR", "TTY", "SDUI"]].drop_duplicates()
        match["icd_code"] = icd_code
        match["icd_term"] = icd_term
        match["level"] = level
        match["is_a"] = 'indirect_rel'

        match = match.loc[:, ["icd_code","icd_term","CODE","STR", "TTY", "SDUI", "level", "is_a"]]
        match.to_csv(r'indirect_mapping_icd10cm.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a')
        
    else:
        print ('match not found: continue')
```

How can I modify my script to write the whole content without any error.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: could you post the complete traceback of your error? You (or any other process) are not opening this file to check the contents while the program is running right?

Comment: No, I am not opening the file

Answer (score 0):

before running your script make sure your text file is closed.

S0,  i can suggest first close your text file if it is opened in any where and then run the script.

i think it will work.

Comment: That sounds believable under Windows (I think, although I don't program with Windows). Under Linux it would be unlikely to cause a permissions error. Perhaps you should ask the OP for clarification regarding their OS platform.

Comment: Yes, it is windows